Complete set of local orthogonal idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_n$
I want to find a set of local orthogonal idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, i. e. such idempotents $e_1, \ldots e_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ that $1 = e_1 + \ldots + e_n$, $e_i e_j = e_j e_i = 0, (i \ne j)$, and $e_i \mathbb{Z}_n e_i$ is local.
I guess is that these can only be $0$ or $1$. We know from CRT that any idempotent in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has form $e = 0\vee1 (\mod p_i^{\alpha_i} \;)$, $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, $p_j$ - prime. Then $e$ can be represented in the form
$$
e = \prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{\alpha_i \gamma_i} (p_i^{\alpha_i} - 1)^{\sigma_i},
$$
in which $\alpha_i, \sigma_i = 0 \vee 1$. Let's take two different idempotents $e_1$ and $e_2, (e_1 \ne e_2)$. Does it follow that $e_1 e_2 \ne 0$?

$1$ and $3$ (or $4$) are idempotents in $\mathbb Z_{6}$, and their product is not $0$

$\Bbb Z_n \cong \prod\limits_{j = 1}^k \Bbb Z_{p_j^{\alpha_j}}$, the unities of the factors correspond to the primitive idempotents (there are $k$ of them in contrast to $2^k$ total idempotents). Here primitive = local.

My typo. I tried to proof that $e_1 e2 \ne 0$

I don't understand.  $3$ and $4$ are idempotents in $\mathbb Z_6$, and their product is $0$

@Amateur_Algebraist It looks like my mistake about the idea of proving $e_1 e_2 \ne 0$. We can take idempotents $e_1 = 1 ( ; \mod p_1^{\alpha_1} ;), \ldots, e_n = 1 (; \mod p_k^{\alpha_k};)$, then $e_1 + \ldots + e_n = 1$ and $e_i e_j = 0$. Is it correct?

Yes, $e_i = 1 \mod p_i^{\alpha_i}$ and $0$ modulo $p_j^{\alpha_j}$, $j \not = i$, is a local idempotent for all $i$, as $\Bbb Z_n e_i$ is (Artinian and) directly irreducible. These are the only ones. Note that in noncommutative rings, the expression of $1$ as a sum of local idempotents need not be unique.
